# Node.js- Does setting a variable to a variable from another file also change that variable in the other file?

Tags: node.js, config

I have a file called config.js that I'm using as a config file:

```
var config = {};

config.defaultCmds = ['modB!', 'addReqs', 'rmReqs', 'listReqs', 'addAdminRole', 'rmAdminRole', 'setHereRequired', 'setCmd', 'commands', 'setDefault', 'replaceReqs'];
config.defaultRaidReqs = [new RegExp('LF[1-5]M|LFG', 'i'), new RegExp('prestige|prest|prest.|normal|anything', 'i'), new RegExp('levi|leviathan|raid|eow|lair|raid lair', 'i'), new RegExp('https://discord.gg/|CR[1-4]', 'i')];
config.defaultCrucibleReqs = [new RegExp('LF[1-4]M|LFG', 'i'), new RegExp('trials|crucible|pvp|quickplay|quick|anything', 'i'), new RegExp('https://discord.gg/|CC[1-5]', 'i')];
config.defaultPveReqs = [new RegExp('LF[1-5]M|LFG', 'i'), new RegExp('prestige|prest|prest.|normal|anything', 'i'), new RegExp('nf|nightfall|anything|rat king|public event|', 'i'), new RegExp('https://discord.gg/|CS[1-4]', 'i')];

config.defaultAdminRoles = ['LEADERSHIP'];

config.defaultHereRequired = false;

config.defaultRaidChannel = "lfg-raid";
config.defaultCrucibleChannel = "lfg-crucible";
config.defaultPveChannel = "lfg-pve";
config.defaultQuestionsChannel = "lfg-questions";

module.exports = config;
```

In my main code Im trying to set variables there to these variables in the config file, but whenever I change a variable in my main code, it also changes the variable in the config.js.
For example when the program starts, it has something like this:

```
const config = require('./config');
cmds = config.defaultCmds;
cmds[0] = 'something';
```

New printing out both cmds[0] and config.defaultCmds[0] would now equal 'something', rather than cmds[0] equals 'something' and config.defaultCmds[0] equals 'modB!', as defined in config.js.

It wouldent make much sense, but does setting a variable to a variable from another file somehow link the two together so if one changes the other changes as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing `cmds = config.defaultCmds;` `cmds` is just pointing to the same array and it does not create a new array.

If you want to create a new array, you can do `cmds = config.defaultCmds.slice()`.

Now `cmds` is a new array on which you can change value without affecting the config object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works, but slice is not really intended for this usage.

```
var cmds =   Object.assign({}, config.defaultCmds)
```